# Broken image multisite

Tags: multisite, images, configuration

I've two wp sites (multisite) with the following config:

> 1#
>
> (Main site) Home: http:// www.mysite.com
>
> Upload Path: wp-content/uploads
>
> Fileupload Url: http:// www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads
>
> 2#
>
> Home: http:// www.mysite.com/en/
>
> Upload Path: wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files
>
> Fileupload Url: http:// www.mysite.com/en/files

My .htaccess has the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

The first site is working 100%, i can upload images, view them on the media library & post edit and they show OK in the page

The second site, when I upload the image, it shows a broken image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsMg4.gif

But when I click the "edit image" button it shows OK: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gMIH.gif

I've checked and the image is on the right folder (http: //www.mysite.com/blogs.dir/2/files/honey.jpg) but it's broken in the admin panel and the site. The url of the broken image is: http: //www.mysite.com/en/files/honey.jpg

I've lost hours trying to fix it through .htaccess and changing the wordpress config but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading several topics about this issue I've found this:

> Issues with old WPMU installs
>
> If you installed WordPress MU in subfolder/subdirectory (not in root folder on your server >via ftp) and you have problem with image library, where thumbnails and images do not show, >you may need to manually add in rewrite rules for your file directories as follows:
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?siteN/files/(.+) wp-content/blogs.dir/N/files/$2 [L]
> ```
>
> Put those below the normal call for uploaded files.

However, this didn't work, i had to replace (or comment) the uploaded files line and change the new one to work in all sites. In the end this is the .htaccess that worked OK:

```
# uploaded files
# RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-content/blogs.dir/N/files/$2 [L]
```

Being 'N' the number of my non-primary site

So, I guess that for each site, you have to add another line changing the number.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Is `blogs.dir` supposed to replaced by the name of an actual directory or is that how you actually have it in your .htaccess file?

Comment: I had it like that. I just changed the N to match the website number. But this was back in 2012, I think wp multisite does not work like that anymore. Are you having the same issue? Maybe this can help: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/blogs-dir-in-wp-above-3-5/

Comment: Thanks. Turns out the issue was that the new server was running NGINX as a reverse proxy but still using Apache to serve the site so I had to edit the NGINX VHOST file.