# Image problem - Multisite image upload broken

Tags: multisite, uploads

I am having a WPMU install in a sub folder and I am facing broken image link problem. There are several solutions online like [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73783/broken-image-multisite)

But nothing worked for me.

I upload images through media in sub sites. They get uploaded to `blogs-dir/sites` folder, but when I look through the inspect element tool, it shows the path to `wp-content/uploads` folder.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just change your .htaccess to this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Just an FYI, it's important to format code as code (use the curly brace buttons in the editor {}) - especially in this case because .htaccess syntax for comments (#) also happens to be markdown syntax that is used in this site's display. So # comments in the .htaccess code were rendered as headings and the "#" left out.